# MongoDB for wearable data like pulse, step count and sleep quality?

Tags: mongodb

We're building an application where we need to store user data from a wearable device that can measure: pulse, step count, and sleep quality.

We're using MongoDB for everything else - user profiles, workouts of different types etc..

The pulse data will only be measured when the user is exercising and not all day. Therefore the pulse data will be linked to already existing workout documents.

But for the step count and sleep data we don't know what would be best practice?

The resolution should be days for step count, and hours for sleep quality. We will probably always download a week at the time from the database, as a minimum.. Maybe more. But never only hours or days. So would that be an argument to create weekly documents for every user? or maybe monthly? Or doesn't it matter, and could just as well be 1 day documents for each user?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Comment: why did you choose MongoDb for that project?

Comment: @derloopkat we have a lot of different data types. What would you've chosen and why?